# Best way to detect failing batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, detection, failure, lifepo4

I have a few IOT products scattered around long distances, they use solar and batteries to run. They are LiFePO<sub>4</sub> 12.4 V systems deployed in the South East US.

I have them report all the data available every 30 minutes; the data includes: SOC, voltage, current output, temperature, timestamp, etc.

I want to put in some metrics that flag when a battery is failing. What metrics should I look for? By "failing" I mean completely dead/will not recharge.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to define "failing" and "about to die".  Do you mean you want to know when a perfectly healthy battery is reaching end of charge, or do you mean you want to know when the battery pack is losing capacity and needs to be replaced?  Both of these functions depend on having a decent state-of-charge indicator, and diagnosing a low-capacity battery is the more difficult problem.

Comment: Yes:
I mean that it will not recharge or is unlikely to recharge. If it's cloudy for 4 days and the battery dies but recharges on the 5th day, I won't send a crew out. if instead the battery won't charge I'll send a crew out

Comment: If it's completely dead it won't be able to report its condition. If other units are responding, one that does not can be assumed to have failed for some reason. Do you have circuitry to avoid total (or excessive) discharge?

Answer (score 1):

Internal resistance:

As the load varies, for each cell, plot voltage vs current and draw a line through the points. The slope of the line (voltage divide by current) is the internal resistance of the cell. Do so for a new battery, then on a regular basis as the battery is in use.

- A sudden increase in resistance is an indication of a cell that is about to become the limiting factor for the entire battery.
- A gradual increase in resistance in all the cells is normal, but consider the voltage sag under load, and be ready to retire the battery before the resistance becomes so high that it would cause the load's low voltage cut-out to trip even though there is still charge in the battery.

Voltage vs SoC:

As the SoC varies, plot cell voltages.

- A cell whose voltage is first to have a high voltage when charging, and the first to have a low voltage when discharging, is an indication of a low capacity cell that is about to become the limiting factor for the entire battery.
- If a cell is the limiting one when charging and another cell is the limiting one when discharging, the battery needs to be balanced
- Capacity fade (a  gradual decrease in capacity) is normal, but consider the run time, and be ready to retire the battery before the capacity becomes so low that it would cause the run time to be shorter than the user expects.